# How to optimize a double for loop with condition on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have these two dataframes :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Points':[0,1,2,3],'Axis1':[1,2,2,3], 'Axis2':[4,2,3,0],'ClusterId':[1,2,2,3]})
df
   Points  Axis1  Axis2  ClusterId
0       0      1      4          1
1       1      2      2          2
2       2      2      3          2
3       3      3      0          3

Neighbour = pd.DataFrame()
Neighbour['Points'] = df['Points']
Neighbour['Closest'] = np.nan
Neighbour['Distance'] = np.nan

Neighbour
   Points  Closest  Distance
0       0      NaN       NaN
1       1      NaN       NaN
2       2      NaN       NaN
3       3      NaN       NaN
```

I would like that the **Closest column** contains **the closest point which is NOT in the same cluster** (ClusterId in df), based on the following distance function, applied to Axis1 and Axis2 :

```
def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dist = sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    return dist
```

And I would like that the **Distance column** contains the **distance between the point and its closest point**.

The following script works but I think it is really not the best way to do in Python :

```
for i in range(len(Neighbour['Points'])): 
    bestD = -1 #best distance
    #bestP for best point
    for ii in range(len(Neighbour['Points'])): 
        if df.loc[i,"ClusterId"] != df.loc[ii,"ClusterId"]: #if not share the same cluster
            dist = distance(df.iloc[i,1],df.iloc[i,2],df.iloc[ii,1],df.iloc[ii,2])
            if dist < bestD or bestD == -1:
                bestD = dist
                bestP = Neighbour.iloc[ii,0]
    Neighbour.loc[i,'Closest'] = bestP
    Neighbour.loc[i,'Distance'] = bestD

Neighbour
   Points  Closest  Distance
0       0      2.0  1.414214
1       1      0.0  2.236068
2       2      0.0  1.414214
3       3      1.0  2.236068
```

Is there a more effective way to fill the Closest and Distance columns (especially, without the for loops)? It might be an appropriate occasion to use map and reduce but I don't really see how.

Comment: How big is your dataframe?

Comment: The real dataframe has currently around 1 000 rows, but it could have around 50 000 latter

Comment: Have you tried with https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html instead of your distance function? Also, you could use `df.iterrows()` for that iteration. That would clean your code quite a bit.

Comment: @alec_djinn no need to use iterrows because scipy does provide a function computing pairwise distance (euclidean, or another one) between array. See `cdist` or `pdist`

Comment: @politinsa Indeed, `apply()` would be perfect for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the distance you can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) on the underlying ndarray of your DataFrame. This might be faster that your double loop.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

>>> distance_matrix = cdist(df.values[:, 1:3], df.values[:, 1:3], 'euclidean')
>>> distance_matrix
array([[0.        , 2.23606798, 1.41421356, 4.47213595],
       [2.23606798, 0.        , 1.        , 2.23606798],
       [1.41421356, 1.        , 0.        , 3.16227766],
       [4.47213595, 2.23606798, 3.16227766, 0.        ]])
>>> np.fill_diagonal(distance_matrix, np.inf) # set diagonal to inf so minimum isn't distance(x, x) = 0
>>> distance_matrix
array([[       inf, 2.23606798, 1.41421356, 4.47213595],
       [2.23606798,        inf, 1.        , 2.23606798],
       [1.41421356, 1.        ,        inf, 3.16227766],
       [4.47213595, 2.23606798, 3.16227766,        inf]])
```

To speed things up you could also check the [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) function instead of the cdist, it's taking way less memory for when you'll have 50_000 rows.
There is also [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) aiming to find the nearest neighbours of a point.

Then you can use `np.argmin` to get the closest distance, and check if the closest point is in the cluster, like this (I didn't try though):

```py
for i in range(len(Neighbour['Points'])):
    same_cluster = True
    while same_cluster:
        index_min = np.argmin(distance_matrix[i])
        same_cluster = (df.loc[i,"ClusterId"] == df.loc[index_min,"ClusterId"])
        if same_cluster:
            distance_matrix[i][index_min] = np.inf
    Neighbour.loc[i,'Closest'] = index_min
    Neighbour.loc[i,'Distance'] = distance_matrix[i][index_min]
```

Comment: Good job ! I tested it and the result is clear : with 1000 rows, mine needs 71 seconds whereas yours needs only 0.6 second... For those who are interested, I used timeit package with start = timeit.default_timer(), stop = timeit.default_timer() and then stop - start

Answer (score 1):

To complete @politinsa answer, the following script allows to compare the performance of both methods :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
import numpy as np
import timeit
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dist = sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    return dist 

X,y = make_moons(n_samples=1000, noise=0.1)
W = list(range(1000))
rs = check_random_state(0)
Z = rs.randint(0, 10, size=(1000,))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Points=W, Axis1=X[:,0], Axis2=X[:,1],ClusterId=Z))
Neighbour = pd.DataFrame()
Neighbour['Points'] = df['Points']
Neighbour['Closest'] = np.nan
Neighbour['Distance'] = np.nan

start = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range(len(Neighbour['Points'])): 
    bestD = -1 #best distance
    for ii in range(len(Neighbour['Points'])): 
        if df.loc[i,"ClusterId"] != df.loc[ii,"ClusterId"]: #if not share the same cluster
            dist = distance(df.iloc[i,1],df.iloc[i,2],df.iloc[ii,1],df.iloc[ii,2])
            if dist < bestD or bestD == -1:
                bestD = dist
                bestP = Neighbour.iloc[ii,0]
    Neighbour.loc[i,'Closest'] = int(bestP)
    Neighbour.loc[i,'Distance'] = bestD

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time initial script: ', stop - start)

start = timeit.default_timer()

distance_matrix = cdist(df.values[:, 1:3], df.values[:, 1:3])
np.fill_diagonal(distance_matrix, np.inf) # set diagonal to inf so minimum isn't distance(x, x) = 0
for i in range(len(Neighbour['Points'])):
    same_cluster = True
    while same_cluster:
        index_min = np.argmin(distance_matrix[i])
        same_cluster = (df.loc[i,"ClusterId"] == df.loc[index_min,"ClusterId"])
        if same_cluster:
            distance_matrix[i][index_min] = np.inf
    Neighbour.loc[i,'Closest'] = index_min
    Neighbour.loc[i,'Distance'] = distance_matrix[i][index_min]
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time @politinsa\'s script: ', stop - start)
```

Out (in seconds):

```
Time initial script:  70.62462342600003
Time @politinsa's script:  0.6489833670000235
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create cartesian product first and and apply new column as distance accordingly using below distance function

```
def distance(row):
    x1 = row.Axis1_x
    y1 = row.Axis2_x
    x2 = row.Axis1_y
    y2 = row.Axis2_y
    dist = math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    return dist


df = pd.DataFrame({'Points':[0,1,2,3],'Axis1':[1,2,2,3], 'Axis2':[4,2,3,0],'ClusterId':[1,2,2,3]})
df['join_key'] = '12345'
df = df.merge(df, how='outer', on='join_key')
df['distance'] = df.apply(distance, axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=['join_key'])
```

So you will see a cartesian df like below

[image]

from now on, you ll see each point to each point distance. I assume that the hardest part is this. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @baranbartu. Interesting approach, I'm testing what we can do from it

Comment: I'm afraid that this approach is not very effective with a large number of rows :/ These dataframes are just simple examples. But the real ones could have tens of thousands rows

Comment: You are definitely right but complexity is same  O(n2), you just use pandas features instead of multiple for loops. Also, as far as i know, df runs distributed according to the CPU power. Basically, In this case, if you want to know closest distance, first you have to calculate all distances unfortunately.